# Divide and conquer algorithm applied in finding a peak in an array.

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

For an array a: a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, … a<sub>k</sub>, … a<sub>n</sub>, a<sub>k</sub> is a peak if and only if a<sub>k-1</sub> ≤ a<sub>k</sub> ≥ a<sub>k+1</sub> when 1 < k and k < n. a<sub>1</sub> is a peak if a<sub>1</sub> ≥ a<sub>2</sub>, and a<sub>n</sub> is a peak if a<sub>n-1</sub> ≤ a<sub>n</sub>. The goal is to find one peak from the array.

A divide and conquer algorithm is given as follows:

```
find_peak(a,low,high):
    mid = (low+high)/2
    if a[mid-1] <= a[mid] >= a[mid+1] return mid // this is a peak;
    if a[mid] < a[mid-1] 
        return find_peak(a,low,mid-1) // a peak must exist in A[low..mid-1]
    if a[mid] < a[mid+1]
        return find_peak(a,mid+1,high) // a peak must exist in A[mid+1..high]
```

Why this algorithm is correct? I think it may suffer from losing half of the array in which a peak exists.

Comment: It really comes down to the assertions; is it true that "a peak must exist in A[low...mid-1]" if a[mid] < a[mid-1]?

Comment: This algorithm assumes an awful lot about the way the data is structured..

Comment: re "I think it may suffer from losing half of the array in which a peak exists." You said earlier you only wanted to find _one_ peak. So it doesn't matter if you lose half the array so long as there is a peak in the other half. Also, have you tried coding up the algorithm and running it in a debugger with some different test cases? Might give you some intuition as to what it is doing.

Comment: This is assuming that the array is holding a smoothing changing function.

Answer (score 7):

The algorithm is correct, although it requires a bit of calculus to prove.
First case is trivial → peak.
Second case is a "half peak", meaning that it has the down slope, but not up.

We have 2 possibilities here:

- The function is monotonically decreasing till a<sub>mid</sub> → a<sub>1</sub> ≥ a<sub>2</sub> is the peak.
- The function is not monotonically decreasing till a<sub>mid</sub> → There is a 1≥k≥mid, for which a<sub>k</sub> ≥ a<sub>k-1</sub>. Let's choose the largest k for which this statement is true → a<sub>k+1</sub> < a<sub>k</sub> ≥ a<sub>k-1</sub> → and that's the peak.

Similar argument can be applied for the third case with the opposite "half peak".

Comment: is it worth adding that this can break down if we have a run of constants at one side or the other?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see your point and it's intuitively right. Can you specify how to prove it?

Comment: @TooTone Nope, it's still valid - 3 equal consecutive values also qualify for a peak according to the problem definition

Comment: @icepack I stand corrected: it's a bit of a non-intuitive definition of peak.